# Access Docker container hosting SFTP from remote machine

Tags: docker

I've got a new Ubuntu install running Docker that I'm trying to use to host an SFTP server. I'm able to access the SFTP server from my local machine, but not within my local network.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is as follows:

```
version: "2.3"
services:
    sftp:
        image: atmoz/sftp
        ports:
          - "2222:22"
        command: foo:pass:1001
        networks:
          - turreta_network
        volumes:
          - "/home/my-name/20220926-ftp/demo-dir:/home/foo/upload"
networks:
  turreta_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Then I run the following commands to bring up the server.

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

I am then able to SFTP into the container on my local machine using:

```
sftp -P 2222 foo@0.0.0.0
sftp -P 2222 foo@[MY_IP]
```

However, when I try to access the SFTP server from another computer on the network via the IP address, it fails with the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host [IP ADDRESS] port 2222: Connection timed out
Connection closed
```

I have opened port 2222 using UFW, and you can see that it allows incoming and outgoing data  using `ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2222                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

2222                       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I know I've not got (straightforward) issues with my router as I spun up a quick local .net server on the machine (`dotnet new webapp`) and ran it. I was able to access the dotnet server from a browser running on my remote machine, so I know I've not got issues with my ports.:

```
sudo dotnet run . -urls http://[IPADDRESS]:2222
```

> Aside, I had to run it with `sudo` which surprised me.

Anyone got any idea what's going on or can help?

### Possible Related Issue

I don't know if this is a related issue, but I'm unable to stop running containers on my box.

If I run `docker stop <container-id>` I get:

```
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: <container_id>: permission denied
```

I'm having to stopo running containers by attaching to them and issuing a `kill` command from within the container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question.

I was suspicious that there was some configuration issue with the box because of the `Possible Related Issue` mentioned above.

I resorted to reinstalling Ubuntu on the box and starting again. The reinstalled box worked correctly.

I'm not sure if "Pave your computer" is an acceptable answer, but it worked for me :)